# How to get actual value from stored procedure on Gridview instead of "System.Data.DataSet"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, dataset

I have a table called Reviews in my Database and there are ratings for FoodQuality, ServiceRating, AtmosphereRating, & PriceRating.

I am binding the data to my Gridview and trying to get the average rating for each section and show it on my Gridview in a `FooterText`.

I am using a stored procedure to select each section and get the average.
Then I am using a method to retrieve a review by an ID and then trying to get that average value to show up.

Instead of getting the actual number I keep getting `System.Data.DataSet`

I have tried to put `.Tables[0].Rows[0][""]` but it's not working out.

Here's my one of my stored Procedures for the FoodQuality Rating:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].GetFoodRatingByID
    @theID int
AS
    SELECT AVG (FoodQuality)
    FROM Reviews
    WHERE RestaurantID = @theID
```

Here's my method:

```
public string GetFoodRatingByID(int id)
        {
            DBConnect objDB = new DBConnect();
            objCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            objCmd.CommandText = "GetFoodRatingByID";

            SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@theID", id);

            sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            sqlParameter.Size = 3;

            objCmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

            objDB.GetConnection();
            DataSet ds = objDB.GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(objCmd);
            string avgFoodRating = ds.ToString();

            objDB.CloseConnection();

            return avgFoodRating;
```

Here's my actual code:

```
                    gvReviews.Columns[0].FooterText = "Average Ratings";
                    gvReviews.Columns[3].FooterText = p.GetFoodRatingByID(restID).ToString();
                    gvReviews.Columns[4].FooterText = p.GetServiceRatingByID(restID).ToString();
                    gvReviews.Columns[5].FooterText = p.GetAtmosRatingByID(restID).ToString();
                    gvReviews.Columns[6].FooterText = p.GetPriceRatingByID(restID).ToString();

                    gvReviews.DataSource = p.GetReviewByRestaurantID(restID);
                    gvReviews.DataBind();
```

I want to be able to see the actual output as the actual average number in each column.

Comment: Have you tried `.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]`? Since you're wanting a scalar anyways, you might want to consider switching from using `DBConnect` to something that provides an `ExecuteScalar` command.

Comment: @JonathonChase that just gets the last number not the average

Comment: You're selecting a single aggregation, there shouldn't be anything returning except a single number.

Comment: @JonathonChase yes I am getting a single number which is what I want but it is not the average number. it's just getting the number in the last row.

Comment: Do you have multiple rows that match the ID you are passing in?

Comment: @pyuntae No, you are getting the average.   If you think you are not, post sample data, expected results, and the results you are getting.